# What is Page fault service time?

Tags: operating-system

I am reading operating systems and having a doubt regarding page fault service time ?

**Average memory access Time = prob. of no page fault (memory access time) 
                     +
 prob. of page fault (Page fault service time)**

My doubt is that what does the page fault service time includes ?

According to me,

First address translation is there in TLB or Page table , but when entry is not found in page table, it means page fault occurred . So, i have to fetch from disk and all the entries get updated in the TLB and as well as page table.

Hence, **page Fault service time = TLB time + page table time + page fetch from disk**

Plz someone confirm it ?

Answer (score 4):

What you are describing is academic Bulls____. There are so many factors that a simple equation like that does not describe the access time. Nonetheless, there are certain idiotic operating systems books that put out stuff like that to sound intellectual (and professors like it for exam questions).

What these people are trying to say is that a page reference will be in memory or not in memory with the two probabilities adding up to 1.0. This is entirely meaningless because the relative probabilities are dynamic. If other processes start using memory, the likelihood of a page fault increases and if other processes stop using memory, the probability declines.

Then you have memory access times. That is not constant either. Accessing a cached memory location is faster than a non-cached location. Accessing memory that is shared by multiple processors and interlocked is slower. This is not a constant either.

Then you have page fault service time. There are soft and hard page faults. A page fault on a demand zero page is different in time for one that has to be loaded from disk. Is the disk access cached or not cached? How much activity is there on the disk?

Oh, is the page table paged? If so, is the page fault on the page table or on the page itself? It could even be both.

Servicing a page fault:

1. The process enters the exception and interrupt handler.
2. The interrupt handler dispatches to the page fault handler.
3. The page fault handler has to find where the page is stored.
4. If the page is in memory (has been paged out but not written to disk), the handler just has to update the page table.
5. If the page is not in memory, the handler has to look up where the page is stored (this is system and type of memory specific).
6. The system has to allocate a physical page frame for the memory.
7. If this is a first reference to a demand zero page, there is no need to read from disk, just set everything to zero.
8. If the page is in a disk cache, get the page from that.
9. Otherwise read the page from disk to the page frame.
10. Reset the process's registers as appropriate.
11. Return to user mode
12. Restart the instruction causing the fault.
    (All of the above have gross simplifications.)

The TLB has nothing really to do with this except that the servicing time is marginally faster if the page table entry in question is in the TLB.

> Hence, page Fault service time = TLB time + page table time + page fetch from disk

Not at all.

Comment: Does page fault service time includes memory access time for demand paging?

Comment: Access time to what? The time to service a fault fault runs from the time the fault hits the interrupt vector until the return from the exception.